# Postgresql 7: How to GROUP BY Month

Tags: php, postgresql

I've a task to implement sql query which need to return all results per months.
My Query is:

```
SELECT tab_1.advert_level_id, tab_3.level, count(tab_1.advert_id) 
FROM table_1 AS tab_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS tab_2 ON tab_2.id = tab_1.advert_id
LEFT JOIN table_3 as tab_3 on tab_1.advert_level_id = tab_3.id
WHERE tab_2.date_published > 1496275200 AND tab_2.date_published < 1498867200
group by tab_1.advert_level_id, tab_3.level
ORDER BY tab_1.advert_level_id ASC
```

I put this query into foreach loop to rebind **start** and **end** timestamp. When this query loop several times it's took too much time and my server crash with message "504 Gateway Time-out". Is there any way to remove the loop and run my query only once as I use Grouping by month? I am not familiar with Grouping by month and I need a little help.

Comment: postgres7? really? also if you want us to help with loop - show the loop?..

Comment: I don't wish to use the loop at all. My loop only change start and end timestamp.

start: 1496275200
end: 1498867200

I would like to take all results from my table grouped by month.

Answer (score 1):

```
select date_trunc('month',current_date)::date;
```

You simply "truncate" your date column to "month" then use that in the group by and select clauses

in your case you may have to convert the "date" column information into something that DATE_TRUNC() will recognize.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. :) You solve my issue. :) 

Best Regards.

Comment: Great. Could you sccpt the answer please? (Click the tick)